# Maven dependency for UserCompatibilityHelper?

Tags: maven, jira, dependency-management, confluence

I hope to add a Maven dependency so that I can use this class in my plugin:

```
com.atlassian.confluence.usercompatibility.UserCompatibilityHelper
```

What dependency should I add?

I installed Atlassian plugin SDK 6.2.14 and it seems that it does cover this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use following dependency :

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.usercompatibility</groupId>
    <artifactId>usercompatibility-confluence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

You can also take a look at Atlassian [Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/preparing-for-confluence-5-2/renamable-users-in-confluence-5-2) about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems that it is part of SDK 5.x and does not come with SDK 6.x. Right?

Comment: yeah, I believe so. In latest versions, you may need to consider using com.atlassian.user I guess.